# JSON data returning nil

Tags: ios, json, swift

I am getting data from my server, and trying to convert that into `JSON`. On my php script I am converting it to `JSON` then sending it over.

Here is my code:

```
let url: NSURL = NSURL(string: "https://xxxxxx.com/myFile.php")!
        let request:NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url as URL)
        let bodyData = "username=\(username.text!)&password=\(password.text!)"
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.httpBody = bodyData.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8);
        request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request as URLRequest, queue: OperationQueue.main)
        {
            (response, data, error) in
            if(error == nil){
                var responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)

                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    let viewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "nextVC") as! ViewController
                    viewController.importData = data!
                    viewController.modalTransitionStyle = .crossDissolve
                    self.present(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
                }
            }

        }
```

ViewController

```
var importData = Data() //when I cast this to NSString and print it I see the JSON correctly.
let json = JSON(data: importData) //  this prints nil.
```

Any reason why?

Comment: show ur tried code

Comment: I did, I've updated my question to make it more clear.

Comment: *"I see the JSON correctly"* – that is fine, but we don't see it. Please post a *self-contained, reproducible* example demonstrating the problem.

Comment: @joethemow Why are you not using `JSONSerialization`?

Comment: I am using swiftyJSON, when I do Data(contentsofURL) it works perfectly fine

Comment: Where have you declared the variable importData ? Inside the class or outside the class?

Comment: I think you mixing two issues, and that you need to clarify. First one: Retrieving JSON from `NSURLConnection`. Then, putting it in another `UIViewController`. Do you get it before the setting it to the VC? Could you share the code of your VC (`viewDidLoad`/`viewDidAppear`, how is declared `importData`, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Try to convert the response to string and see if the response from server is valid.

```
var dataString = String(data: importedData, encoding: .utf8)
print(dataString)
```

Comment: Yes it is returning the data, but it looks very ugly with a bunch of `\n`'s

Comment: make string as data and then use `JSONSerialization`

Comment: Just run this printed string data in some JSON formatter to make sure its a valid JSON.